# Change directory for use with CMD

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, ssh

I have the SSH command line utility installed via chocolatey on Windows 8. The only problem is, it has an ssh key path with Linux OS' in mind, this means that the path is `/home/roconnor/.ssh`. This is fine, but when I try anything in SSH from the command line, it doesn't like the directory (for obvious reasons). I was wondering if it's possible to change this path to `C:/Users/roconnor/.ssh`? I'm using forward slash because it's recognized by Linux shells (I use cygwin and git bash as well) and Windows command prompts.

Comment: Did you try to write the _path to that directory_  as it happears in windows? Maybe omit the drive and if needed try to use `'...'` to fix the contents of the string.

Comment: @Hastur When I executed `ssh-keygen` the first time, I didn't foresee this issue and I kept the `/home/roconnor/.ssh` directory... The directory `C:\Users\roconnor\.ssh` exists, and the directory `/home/roconnor/.ssh` points to it, but I was wondering if it was possible to change the saved path for `/home/roconnor/.ssh` to `C:/Users/roconnor/.ssh`

Comment: I don't know chocolatey but it seems it installed a normal version of ssh compiled for windows. If I correctly undestood your issue, in the setup directory of ssh it should be stored the path for the user ssh dir. There you have to change the string. Test it before passing from command line with the option relative to your version, the path of your ssh keys; then update the config file.